# TikZ/PGF: I can't find file `tikzlibrarycircuit.code.tex' error

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I am trying to use the `circuit` library from TikZ/PGF 2.1, but get the following error when I call LaTeX:

```
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.code.tex"
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex"
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count90
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen140
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen141
\tikz@lasty=\dimen142
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen143
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen144
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen145
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen146
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@tempbox=\box34
\tikztreelevel=\count91
\tikznumberofchildren=\count92
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count93
\tikz@fig@count=\count94

("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count95
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count96
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count97
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count98

("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\circuits\tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex"
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex"
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex"
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\modules\pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex"
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen147
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen148
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen149
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen150
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen151
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count99
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen152
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen153
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box35
)
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\libraries\decorations\pgflibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex"))
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pg
f\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex"
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2009/09/04 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.6)
)
\tikz@lib@circ@count=\count100
\tikzcircuitssizeunit=\dimen154
)
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\My Documents\LaTeX\tikz_circuit_error.aux"
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
 ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

! I can't find file `tikzlibrarycircuit.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.227 ....misc,calc,positioning,plotmarks,circuit}

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.227 ....misc,calc,positioning,plotmarks,circuit}

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows XP.

Now a file called `tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex` is present in the `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\circuits` directory (rather than the `tikzlibrarycircuit.code.tex` with no `s` mentioned in the error). Removing the `s` in the file name results in the same error, so I don't think LaTeX is looking in the right directory. I also don't know how you get to see what directory LaTeX actually looked in as the command is truncated as above.

Is this an error in `tikz`, and how can I fix it?

## Update #

Below is a minimal example demonstrating the error:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC, scale=1.2]
        \draw (0,0) to [diode] (0,2) 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Replacing `\usetikzlibrary{circuit}` with `\usetikzlibrary{circuits}` results in the following output:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circuit ee IEC' and I am 
going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC, scale=1.2]

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.


! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/diode' and I am going to 
ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8         \draw (0,0) to [diode] (0,2)
                                   ;
(That was another \errmessage.)

[1]
("C:\Documents and Settings\s0237326\My Documents\LaTeX\tikz_circuit_error.aux"
) )
```

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: ok, will bear in mind

Comment: When you say "removing the `s` in the file name ..." do you mean that you change the filename **on the disk** or do you change the word `circuit` to `circuits` in the `\usetikzlibrary` in the document?

Comment: Actuall, I've done both, but above I have the word 'circuit' in the \usetikzlibrary command, and tried changing the filename on disk to 'tikzlibrarycircuit.code.tex'. If I use 'circuits' in \usetikzlibrary no attempt is made to load the library and I get error relating to unknown commands like resistor etc.

Comment: Changing the filename isn't a good idea as other packages may rely on that file and know it by that filename.  Also, TeX uses a caching system to know where its files are located and changing the filename doesn't update this cache.  So you should definitely use the word `circuits` in the `\usetikzlibrary` command and leave the file name alone.  Can you edit your question to include the error that you get when you use `circuits`?  Also, include the section of the log file where it loads the library files (search for the word "plotmarks" since you're using that library and include lines nearby)

Comment: @crobar: Update your package cache using the MikTeX package manager and see if it helps.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for PGF, I think that you're loading the wrong library.  The `circuits` library itself doesn't define anything directly useful to the end user, rather it lays a foundation which is built on by other circuit packages.  So you need to load a different library corresponding to what you want to do (which will then itself load the circuit library).  If you want resistors, then you probably want the `circuits.ee` library.

Comment: Okay, I'm right.  You are loading the wrong library.  (I also got it wrong in my previous comment, by the way.  There are actually _three_ levels involved here).  I've posted a minimal file that works on my system.  Try that and see if you still get any errors.

Comment: @Martin: To avoid that you confuse a miktex user: The equivalent to ls-R files in TeXLive are the "FNDB"s (file name data bases) in miktex. They are not updated through the package manager but in the "option manager" MikTeX Settings. Depending on the root for which you want to update the database you will have to use either the admin or the user version of MikTeX Setting.

Comment: @Ulrike: Thanks for pointing this out. I hardly never use MikTeX myself.

Comment: A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Ulrike can you please clarify? I get the error "I can't find file `tikzlibraryshadings.code.tex'" in Miktex after including \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{shadings} and installing all packages starting with tikz manually from the package manager. As you suggest, I tried to "Refresh FNDB" and "Update Format" under Miktex Options/Settings (admin and non-admin versions), without any luck. The damn error persits. Can you help out?

Comment: @Steve06: Enable on-the-fly installation and try again. And check that you didn't make a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that you are loading the wrong TikZ library for what you intend to do.

Here's a fairly minimal working example of the `circuits` library from TikZ (basically copied from the manual and made in to a complete document).  Try running this and see if you still get errors.  In particular, note the name of the library being loaded.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to [diode={light emitting}] (3,0)
  to [resistor={adjustable}] (3,3)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: TikZ with circuits]

Comment: Your example works, with the crucial difference being \usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC} rather than \ustikzlibrary{circuits}.

Comment: @crobar: Exactly so.  I'll admit that it is a little confusing - as you can guess from my comments on your original question then it took me two goes to get the right library!  The PGF manual also seems a little more geared to library writers than end users so it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 1):

> l.227 ....misc,calc,positioning,plotmarks,circuit}

I assume that is part of `\usetikzlibrary{....misc,calc,positioning,plotmarks,circuit}`.
Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, not just code snippets or error messages.

It should be `circuits` not `circuit`. Renamed the library file `tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex` to `tikzlibrarycircuit.code.tex` manually is first of all a very bad idea and won't be noted by (La)TeX until you update the file name cache (a file called `ls-R`). (La)TeX doesn't search for the files directly because that would be to slow but uses such files instead. Modern version actually search the users TEXMF tree for this files in every run if no `ls-R` file is present there.

Simply changing `circuit` to `circuits` should fix this issue. If you can't change the code for any funny reason notify the original author. A workaround then would be to place a file called `tikzlibrarycircuit.code.tex` which simply hold the line `\usetikzlibrary{circuits}` in the same directory of your document or into your local TEXMF tree (there in a subdirectory `tex/latex/pgf/`).

Comment: I don't think this is the fix, I have added a minimal example (as I should have done) and output to show why. Thanks though.

Comment: actually, you are sort of right, sorry!